# Save Grid Layout Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, devexpress

I have this in grid settings:

```
    var gridLayoutRepository = new GridLayoutRepository();

    settings.ClientLayout = (s, e) =>
    {
        Debug.Write(e.LayoutData);

        if (e.LayoutMode == ClientLayoutMode.Loading)
        {
            e.LayoutData = gridLayoutRepository.Load();
        }
        else
        {
            gridLayoutRepository.Save(e.LayoutData);
        }
    };
```

I want to have one button for saving gridstate in database and one button for resetting it. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible this way. In grid settings must save grid state:

```
settings.ClientLayout = (s, e) =>
    {
        if (e.LayoutMode == ClientLayoutMode.Loading)
        {
            if (Session["myGridState"] != null)
                e.LayoutData = (string)Session["myGridState"];
        }
        else
            Session["myGridState"] = e.LayoutData;
    };
```

Then on button click you should save grid state like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SaveLayoutData() {
    $.getJSON("@Url.Action("SaveLayoutData", "MyController" })", null,
        function (result) {
            if(result == 'success') {
                alert("Layout save success");
            }
        });
}
</script>
```

In Controller:

```
    public JsonResult SaveLayoutData()
    {
       _gridStateRepository.Save(Session["myGridState"]);
       return Json("success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

When you are loading grid you should load grid state from database and write it in Session["myGridState"]